# Как вывести оставшееся время видео в блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простое HTML5-видео. Можно ли в отдельный блок вывести оставшееся время видео? Чтобы в блоке таймер считал, сколько осталось до конца видео?

```
<video class="video js-video">
    <source src="./video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="countdown">Тут выводим оставшееся время до конца видео</div>
```

Comment: `const video = document.querySelector('video.js-video'); const timeLeft = video. duration - video. currentTime;`

Comment: Да, будет выводиться в секундах. Но как это перевести в формат минуты:секунды (например 09:52)?

Comment: Попробуйте подумать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основываясь на [своём ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1494858/1494871#1494871), вот решение:

```js
let video = document.querySelector('video')
let countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown')

video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', setCountdown)

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', setCountdown)

function setCountdown() {
  let secondsLeft = video.duration - video.currentTime
  let timeLeft = convertSeconds(secondsLeft)

  countdown.textContent = timeLeft
}

function convertSeconds(sec) {
  let date = new Date(1970, 0, 0, 0, 0, +sec || 0)
  let time = date.toLocaleTimeString('ru')

  return time
}
```

```html
<video class="video js-video" controls>
    <source src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fe863385e163e3b0f92dc53/2017/04/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="countdown">00:00:00</div>
```