# Как перевести секунды в минуты и секунды в формате XX:XX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как перевести секунды (например - 578 секунд) в минуты и секунды, чтобы минуты и секунды выводились в таком формате: 10:39, 05:02 (то есть если минут или секунд меньше 10, то вначале выводится 0)?

Comment: `padEnd`, `padStart` вам в помочь.

Comment: Кстати, а если секунд будет настолько много, что наберётся более одного часа (к примеру), что тогда делать?

Comment: Мда... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: @FrontEnder007, пожалуйста, выберите лучший во вашему мнению ответ, который лучше всего решает вашу задачу. Чтобы это сделать, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа (в верхней его части).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод секунд в удобный для чтения формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225570/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как перевести секунды (например - 578 секунд) в минуты и секунды, чтобы минуты и секунды выводились в таком формате: 10:39, 05:02

Например таким образом можно перевести...

```js
const s = 578 
console.log(sToStr(s))

//
function sToStr(s) {
  let m = Math.trunc(s / 60) + ''
  s = (s % 60) + ''
  return m.padStart(2, 0) + ':' + s.padStart(2, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Без учета часов. Для них логика будет примерно такой же

```js
function nilFirst(t) {
  if (t.toString().length === 1) return '0' + t;
  return t.toString();
}

function toTime(sec = 0) {
  return nilFirst(Math.trunc(sec / 60)) + ':' + nilFirst(sec % 60)

}

console.log(toTime(0))
console.log(toTime(60))
console.log(toTime(61))
console.log(toTime(110))
console.log(toTime(75))
console.log(toTime(578))
console.log(toTime(978))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, это самый просто способ решить вашу задачу:

```js
log(578)
log(123)
log(42)
log(9999)
log('42')
log('Hello!')
log(NaN)

function log(sec) {
  console.log(sec, '->', convertSeconds(sec))
}

function convertSeconds(sec) {
  let date = new Date(1970, 0, 0, 0, 0, +sec || 0)
  let time = date.toLocaleTimeString('ru')

  return time
}
```

#### Как с этим работать?

Всё просто, у функции `convertSeconds` есть два аргумента, первый `sec`, туда вы должны вводить секунды, если число не валидное, тогда вместо него будет 0. Функция `log` была лишь для примера, чтобы можно было увидеть результаты.

Comment: Зачем нужна переменная includeHours, если 1 час = 60 * 60 секунд? "По идее", оно не надо.

Comment: @InDevX `includeHours` нужен для того, чтобы "отрезать" часы, если требуется. По вопросу не совсем понятно что с ними делать, так что я сделал вот так.

Comment: Оно не нужно. Человек ерундой страдает, ему надо показывать оставшееся время просмотра видео, ничего не надо отрезать

Comment: @InDevX давно у вас хрустальный шар? 

Comment: [Час, или около того](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494844/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: @InDevX ах вот оно что, ну тогда да, логично.